# Firebase adding data to Array but still empty

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXns2.png)

```
import UIKit

class Connecting {

let refHandler = Firebase(url: "https://-unique-link-.firebaseio.com/handlers")

var handlerID: [AnyObject] = []

func getHandlerStatus() {
        refHandler.queryOrderedByChild("status").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let status = snapshot.value["status"] as? Int {
                if status == 0 {
                    self.handlerID.append(snapshot.key)
                    print(self.handlerID)
                } else {
                    //Do Nothing
                }
            }
        })
}

func handlerIDReturn() -> NSArray {
    print(handlerID)
    return handlerID
}

}
```

handlerID array is filled but when i check, its empty. :( please help
Ive updated with all the codes.

Here is a calling code. I use button to call each fund

```
@IBAction func callerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    Connecting().getHandlerStatus()
}
@IBAction func button2nd(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(Connecting().handlerIDReturn())
}
```

Comment: When does your `handlerIDReturn` code run? Your block will run on a background thread, so perhaps you're calling `handlerIDReturn` before it has finished?

Comment: no sir. I only call handlerIDReturn ONLY after the above func has added data to array.when "print(self.handlerID)" show data. i wait about 5 sec and then call the handlerIDReturn().

Comment: Can you include the surrounding code? Are you sure you're calling both of these methods on the same object instance?

Comment: I've copy all the code and pasted. I'm so lost.

Comment: What about the code from where you're calling these methods?

Comment: i use buttons to call each func. I've uploaded the code

Comment: There's your problem - `Connecting()` creates a new instance every time. I will put it in an answer where there's better formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create just one instance of `Connecting` and use that. At the moment, every call to `Connecting()` is giving you a new object.

```
let connecting = Connecting()

@IBAction func callerButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    connecting.getHandlerStatus()
}
@IBAction func button2nd(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(connecting.handlerIDReturn())
}
```